# Return all values from one array which do not exist in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays which look like this :

```
$has_end_date = ['value123' , 'value132'];
$has_no_end_date = ['value123' , 'value256'];
```

Now I wish to return the **unique** values from `$has_no_end_date` that **doesn't appear** in `$has_end_date`.

**This is what I tried :**

I tried to merge the two arrays together and then find the unique values. But that did not work, i will get the unique of both of them. 
I am only looking for the unique different values from `$has_no_end_date` array.

Comment: have you tried [array_diff($has_no_end_date, $has_end_date)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) ? If required unique then [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: So the answer for this is `['value256']`?

Comment: @vivek_23 Yes sir

Comment: @DrakulaPredator I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to get the difference and [array_unique()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to return unique values.

```
$difference = array_unique(array_diff($has_no_end_date, $has_end_date));
print_r($difference);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/3oLHA  AND https://3v4l.org/7aEFW

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_diff`

```
$a1 = ['value123' , 'value132'];
$a2 = ['value123' , 'value256'];

$diff = array_diff($a2, $a1);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($diff);
```

Output :-

```
Array
(
  [1] => value256
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) if you want to fetch that data,

```
print_r(array_unique(array_diff($has_no_end_date, $has_end_date)));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/N40cY).